# Finding an item based on its enumerable property

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List where the Item object has a List inside of it.  Can I use the built-in Find of the list to return the Item that has a particular set of Data objects inside of it?

Something like (Psuedo-like code):

```
users = List<Item>(new Item {name = "Bob, data = new List<Data>()}, new Item {name = "Bill", data = new List<Data>()})

users.Find(i => i.data.key == "foo" && i.data.value == "bar")
```

Comment: What is the type of property `data`? You're accessing `.key` and `.value` but a `List<T>` doesn't have such properties.

Comment: Your question basically is: "I have a `List<T>` object, can I use its `Find` method?" Answer: "why not?" If your question is *how* to use it, please reword it.

Comment: Data class has a key and a value property.

Comment: My question is how can I find an object in a list of objects based on that state of another list within a given object...

Answer (score 3):

You can use linq-expression inside linq-expression. For instance:

`users.Find(i => i.data.Any(a => <your condition>))`

Answer (score 3):

`Find` is specific method for `List<T>`, but `IEnumerable<T>` has the same extension method, namely `FirstOrDefault` it's contained in the `System.Linq` namespace and you can use it like this:

```
users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.data.key == "foo" && i.data.value == "bar")
```

But if you are using only `List<T>` it doesn't really matters what you are going to pick.